# Customise Ubuntu 12.04 login screen logo with yours

Tags: login-screen

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed.
Can someone tell me how can I change/replace the Ubuntu login logo with mine or my name?

Please give full steps involved, because I am new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Change the image `/usr/share/unity-greeter/logo.png` with what do you wish, but keep the same name (`logo.png`) for the image.

First, copy your actual Ubuntu logo in a safety location, using [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
cp /usr/share/unity-greeter/logo.png ~/Pictures/ubuntu_logo.png
```

Then copy a new logo in `/usr/share/unity-greeter/`:

```
sudo cp  ~/Pictures/google_logo.png /usr/share/unity-greeter/logo.png
```

After a system restart you can see the difference:

[image: login screen]